# Wordpress: looping trought images not working with list_files()

Tags: wordpress

I'm trying to loop througt all images of a certain folder with the following script:

```
function loopImages(){
            $imagePath = bloginfo('template_url') . '/assets/images/' . 'casa_intera';
            echo $imagePath;
            $fileList = list_files( $imagePath, 2 );
            foreach ( $fileList as $file ) {
              echo '<img src="' . $imagePath . $file . '" alt="" data-fancybox="gallery" loading="lazy">';
            }
          }
          loopImages();
```

It only echoes the `$imagePath`as `http://localhost:8888/wordpress/wp-content/themes/casale-wp/assets/images/casa_intera` which is correct, but doesn't output the rest.

Thanks

EDIT
currently I have this code:

```
function loopImages(){
            $imagePath = bloginfo('template_url') . '/assets/images/' . 'casa_intera';
            $fileList = list_files( $imagePath, 2 );
            foreach ( $fileList as $file ) {
              var_dump( $file );
            }
          }
          loopImages();
```

But I only get this back as an HTML item

> "        http://localhost:8888/wordpress/wp-content/themes/casale-wp"

Comment: Where are you trying to do this?

Comment: Try just running `var_dump($file);` inside the loop, skipping the entire img tag for now, just for debugging purposes.

Comment: @HowardE in a content file that is rendered inside a page file

Comment: @ChrisHaas added, and I also tried to add it as `var_dump($fileList)` after the variable to see it but it still gets back the same thing (see edit)

Comment: `list_files` is for use in the admin, but not on the front end.

Answer (score 0):

At the end I went with this solution.

```
function loopImages(){
            $imagePath = get_template_directory() . '/your/images/directory/';
            $basePath = get_template_directory_uri(); . '/your/images/directory/';
            $imageList = scandir( $imagePath );
            foreach( $imageList as $image ){
              echo '<img src="' . $basePath . $image . '" alt="" data-fancybox="gallery" loading="lazy">';
            }
          }
          loopImages();
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an option using `glob` to get all jpeg files in a directory. The `list_files` function is an admin function and will not work on the front end.

```
<?php
function loopImages() {
    $image_directory  = '/assets/images/casa_intera/';
    $image_path       = get_stylesheet_directory() . $image_directory . '*.jpg'; // get all jpeg files.
    $file_list        = glob( $image_path );
    foreach ( $file_list as $file ) {
        echo '<img src="' . esc_url( get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . $image_directory . basename( $file ) ) . '" alt="" data-fancybox="gallery" loading="lazy">';
    }
}
loopImages();
?>
```